# SQL Query not turning out correctly

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables and a query where I want to output the text of the different ids.

Col1 and Col2 of Table A is a Foreign Key to the PK of Table B

```
Table A 
PK  Col1  Col2
1    2      3

Table B
PK  Col1
 2   test
 3   test1
```

Query:

```
    select 'This is a ' + B.Col1 + 'and this is' + B.Col1 from TableA r inner join TableB k on r.Col1 = k.PK
```

inner join TableB t on r.Col2 = t.PK'

Result I want

```
This is a test and this is test1
```

Results Im getting

```
This is a test and this is test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
select 
'This is a ' + k1.Col1 +
'and this is' + k2.Col1
from TableA r 
inner join TableB k1 on r.Col1 = k1.PK 
inner join TableB k2 on r.Col2 = k2.PK
```

And btw, realise that when you use + to concat columns. That if one of the column is Null that the result string will be null.
Use CONCAT if you want to avoid that.